# Get marked field on tkinter text box

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, textbox

How do I get the marked data from a tkinter text box,is there an event for that.
If I mark a field in a text box can I retrieve it

Comment: How do you define "marked data"? Are you asking about when you click and drag to make a selection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very simple. To get the selected text go `text.selection_get()`. To see if any text is selected go

```
 def search():
    if text.tag_ranges("sel"):
        text_var=text.selection_get()
        #do something with the text
    else:
        pass
    root.after(500, search) #equivelant of a while loop
```

Comment: Yes I click and drag to mark a section of text within the text box. So as soon as I mark it I need to get that string

Comment: Thanks Jonah will try it out

Comment: Accept what ?   Plus if anyone would like a copy of the code i'll put it on github.  the code scans current mirc log for 4 character stock symbols

Comment: The answer. Click the grey tick next to the answer to show that the question works. This means that other people don't waste their time answering a question that already has an answer. And yes please! I'd like a copy of the code.